# Will a Macbook Pro retina 15" from 2012 support WQHD resolution (3440 x 1440)?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, resolution

I'm interested in buying the [Dell U3415W](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PXYRMPE) for my mid 2012 MBPr 15". I know that thunderbolt 1 can drive regular 1440p displays such as a 2560 x 1440, however can it drive the Dell's wider resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually tried it, and it worked! Full 3440 x 1440 resolution at 60 Hz using thunderbolt to mini display port.

Answer (score 0):

No, according to [EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.7-15-mid-2012-retina-display-specs.html)

> This model supports a simultaneous maximum resolution up to 2560x1600 on two external displays via Thunderbolt. Alternately, it can support
>   a single display up to 2560x1600 via Thunderbolt and a single display
>   up to 1920x1200 via HDMI. Although it can theoretically power all
>   three external displays, as confirmed by a helpful reader, it runs too
>   hot with three displays connected.